# Как получить имя залогиненого пользователя?

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить имя залогиненого пользователя и прочую информацию пользователя? Буду рад парочке простых примеров, спасибо.

```
<?php

if (!empty($_COOKIE['sid'])) {
    // check session id in cookies
    session_id($_COOKIE['sid']);
}

session_start();
require_once 'classes/Auth.class.php';

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PHP Ajax Authorization</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <?php if (Auth\User::isAuthorized()): ?>
                <h1>Your are welcome!</h1>
                <form class="ajax" method="post" action="./ajax.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="logout">
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Logout</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            <?php else: ?>
                <form class="form-signin ajax" method="post" action="./ajax.php">
                    <div class="main-error alert alert-error hide"></div>
                    <input name="username" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Имя пользователя" autofocus>
                    <input name="password" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Пароль">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input name="remember-me" type="checkbox" value="remember-me" checked> Remember me
                    </label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="login">
                    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                    <div class="alert alert-info" style="margin-top:15px;">
                        <p>Not have an account? <a href="/register.php">Register it.</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- /container -->
        <script src="./vendor/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/ajax-form.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

namespace Auth;

class User
{
    private $id;
    private $username;
    private $db;
    private $user_id;

    private $db_host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "php";
    private $db_user = "php";
    private $db_pass = "php";

    private $is_authorized = false;

    public function __construct($username = null, $password = null)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->connectDb($this->db_name, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_host);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->db = null;
    }

    public static function isAuthorized()
    {
        if (!empty($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
            return (bool) $_SESSION["user_id"];
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function passwordHash($password, $salt = null, $iterations = 10)
    {
        $salt || $salt = uniqid();
        $hash = md5(md5($password . md5(sha1($salt))));

        for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; ++$i) {
            $hash = md5(md5(sha1($hash)));
        }

        return array('hash' => $hash, 'salt' => $salt);
    }

    public function getSalt($username) {
        $query = "select salt from users where username = :username limit 1";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(
            array(
                ":username" => $username
            )
        );
        $row = $sth->fetch();
        if (!$row) {
            return false;
        }
        return $row["salt"];
    }

    public function authorize($username, $password, $remember=false)
    {
        $query = "select id, username from users where
            username = :username and password = :password limit 1";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $salt = $this->getSalt($username);

        if (!$salt) {
            return false;
        }

        $hashes = $this->passwordHash($password, $salt);
        $sth->execute(
            array(
                ":username" => $username,
                ":password" => $hashes['hash'],
            )
        );
        $this->user = $sth->fetch();

        if (!$this->user) {
            $this->is_authorized = false;
        } else {
            $this->is_authorized = true;
            $this->user_id = $this->user['id'];
            $this->saveSession($remember);
        }

        return $this->is_authorized;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        if (!empty($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
            unset($_SESSION["user_id"]);
        }
    }

    public function saveSession($remember = false, $http_only = true, $days = 7)
    {
        $_SESSION["user_id"] = $this->user_id;

        if ($remember) {
            // Save session id in cookies
            $sid = session_id();

            $expire = time() + $days * 24 * 3600;
            $domain = ""; // default domain
            $secure = false;
            $path = "/";

            $cookie = setcookie("sid", $sid, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $http_only);
        }
    }

    public function create($username, $password) {
        $user_exists = $this->getSalt($username);

        if ($user_exists) {
            throw new \Exception("User exists: " . $username, 1);
        }

        $query = "insert into users (username, password, salt)
            values (:username, :password, :salt)";
        $hashes = $this->passwordHash($password);
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);

        try {
            $this->db->beginTransaction();
            $result = $sth->execute(
                array(
                    ':username' => $username,
                    ':password' => $hashes['hash'],
                    ':salt' => $hashes['salt'],
                )
            );
            $this->db->commit();
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $this->db->rollback();
            echo "Database error: " . $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }

        if (!$result) {
            $info = $sth->errorInfo();
            printf("Database error %d %s", $info[1], $info[2]);
            die();
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function connectdb($db_name, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_host = "localhost")
    {
        try {
            $this->db = new \pdo("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
        } catch (\pdoexception $e) {
            echo "database error: " . $e->getmessage();
            die();
        }
        $this->db->query('set names utf8');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Эх, наверное, много прошу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В адресную строку прописываешь:

```
site.ru/index.php?id=1
```

И делаешь вывод:

**index.php**

```
$result = ("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id='$_GET[id]'"); //выводим из таблицы users строку id в которой есть цифра 1, то есть id=1
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //устанавливаем переменную
echo $row[name]; //вывод имя пользователя id1
```

Comment: И получаем SQL инъекцию!